# Generating Warnings for Undocumented AS3 Members? (ASDoc)

Tags: actionscript-3, documentation-generation, asdoc

I have a Flash (AS3) component library that I'm distributing, and I want to make sure that it's fully documented for each release. One of the things I really liked about Microsoft's automatic doc generation for C# was that I could have my compiler generate warnings (on every compile) for any public member that wasn't documented in their doc tagging format.

I found this extremely helpful for me to make sure I had fully documented all of my code.

Is there a way to turn on a similar thing for ASDoc?

Thanks for any advice and tips -- I would love for this to work from within Eclipse / Flex Builder, but I'm okay using Ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not yet in there, but it's now [logged as a feature request in Adobe's tracker](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-3709).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following switch:

```
-exclude-dependencies false
```

From [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_1.html):

> Whether all dependencies found by the compiler are documented. If true, the dependencies of the input classes are not documented.
>
> The default value is false.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, though I don't think this option does quite what I'm looking for.